# Mysql update table by joining another table

Tags: mysql, join

I'm having below tables,

Table **product**,

```
product_id | name 
-----------------------
      1    | product 1 
      2    | Product 2
      3    | Product 3     
      4    | product 4    
      5    | product 5  
      .    | ....
      .    | ....
```

Table **product_to_zone**,

```
product_id | zone_id 
--------------------
     1     | 10 
     1     | 11
     2     | 10    
     2     | 11
```

Is there any way to add **zone_id 10,11** as default for all my unassigned products in **product_to_zone** table (i.e for product_id 3,4,5 )

Comment: do you want to update your **product_to_zone** table? if there is a single product_id as in your case suppose 3 then what do you want to assign either 10 or 11?

Comment: yes kandel i need to update product_to_zone table. The concept is simple, a single product can be assigned to multiple zones like how it was in product_to_zone table. I need to assign for both 10 & 11

Comment: I think you don't need to `update` here , just `insert` likes (3,10)(3,11) | (4,10)(4,11) | (5,10)(5,11) ?

Comment: It's a sample data, I have more than 5,000 products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly like this:-

```
SELECT a.product_id, a.name, b.zone_id
FROM products a
INNER JOIN product_to_zone b
ON a.product_id = b.product_id
UNION
SELECT a.product_id, a.name, 10
FROM products a
LEFT OUTER JOIN product_to_zone b
ON a.product_id = b.product_id
WHERE b.product_id IS NULL
UNION
SELECT a.product_id, a.name, 11
FROM products a
LEFT OUTER JOIN product_to_zone b
ON a.product_id = b.product_id
WHERE b.product_id IS NULL
```

If you just want to add the unassigned ones then something like this:-

```
INSERT INTO product_to_zone (product_id, zone_id )
SELECT a.product_id, 10
FROM products a
LEFT OUTER JOIN product_to_zone b
ON a.product_id = b.product_id
WHERE b.product_id IS NULL
UNION
SELECT a.product_id, 11
FROM products a
LEFT OUTER JOIN product_to_zone b
ON a.product_id = b.product_id
WHERE b.product_id IS NULL
```

Comment: No problem. Remember that the 2nd is going to only add records if there is no matching product_to_zone record. Hence if there is already one match for zone_id of 10 then it will not add one for 11 (this seems to be what you require, but just confirming it)

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO product_to_zone (product_id, zone_id)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT (product_id, '10') FROM product WHERE product_id NOT IN
(SELECT a.product_id from product a JOIN product_to_zone b GROUP BY a.product_id)
 UNION
 SELECT (product_id, '11') FROM product WHERE product_id NOT IN
(SELECT a.product_id from product a JOIN product_to_zone b GROUP BY a.product_id));
```

This should get all the products that are still missing in product_to_zone and insert then into product_to_zone with zone_id 10 and 11.

EDIT: If you want to have this done automatically for future products, make a trigger for it.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_product_to_zone AFTER INSERT ON product
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO product_to_zone (product_id, zone_id)
    VALUES (NEW.product_id, '10');
    INSERT INTO product_to_zone (product_id, zone_id)
    VALUES (NEW.product_id, '11');
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer refers to setting those defaults on inserts/updates/deletes, not on setting the values to the already existing records which are addressed by other responses.

You could do this in a stored procedure that gets executed on insert/update, but I'd recommend you to do it at the application level (ie in PHP/Perl/Ruby/Python, or whatever your app is written in).

This is rather complex business logic, because of the following questions:

- what happens when you only have 1 record in the `product_to_zone`?
- what happens when you delete 1 of the 2 records in the `product_to_zone`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a procedure to insert the products that are not yet assigned to a zone (or create a procedure to do something different) like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE assignProductsToZones ()
BEGIN
  DECLARE DECLARE pId INT;
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT product_id FROM product p where not exists (select 1 from product_to_zone ptz where p.product_id=ptz.product_id);
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

OPEN cur1;

read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO pId;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    INSERT INTO product_to_zone (product_id, zone_id) VALUES (pId,11);
    INSERT INTO product_to_zone (product_id, zone_id) VALUES (pId,12);
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur1;
END;
```

And then just call the procedure:

```
CALL assignProductsToZones();
```

You might want to schedule the call to run periodically or use it in a trigger when inserting a new product in de products table.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO product_to_zone (product_id, zone_id)
SELECT product_id, 10 FROM product WHERE product_id NOT IN (SELECT product_id FROM product_to_zone WHERE zone_id IN (10, 11))
UNION
SELECT product_id, 11 FROM product WHERE product_id NOT IN (SELECT product_id FROM product_to_zone WHERE zone_id IN (10, 11));
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do that in 2 ways:

- if You have unique indexes on both collumns on product_to_zone

INSERT IGNORE into product_to_zone
(select product_id, 11 from product);

INSERT IGNORE into product_to_zone
(select product_id, 10 from product);

- or if not You can use tips from people above

Comment: why `insert ignore` is bad idea ?